# 2 images that swap when I tap on either one

Tags: android

What the title says. At first, I created a method to swap from one image to the other one, and it works. When I add the 2nd method though, to reverse the action and swap back to the first one, nothing changes. It does not even revert from the first image to the second one. Below is the code:

```
public void fade(View view) {

    ImageView laxus = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.laxus_shirt);
    ImageView laxos2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.laxus2);
    laxus.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
    laxos2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);

}

public void fadetoblack(View view) {

    ImageView laxusius = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.laxus_shirt);
    ImageView laxosios2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.laxus2);
    laxosios2.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000);
    laxusius.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000);

}
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `start()` to trigger the animation.

```
laxus.animate().alpha(0f).setDuration(1000).start();
laxos2.animate().alpha(1f).setDuration(1000).start();
```

I would suggest you to use Util method to perform crossfading. Something like below

```
public static void crossFade(View incomingView, View outGoingView, int outGoingViewVisibility) {
 outGoingView.setAlpha(1);

 ViewCompat.animate(outGoingView).alpha(0).setListener(new ViewPropertyAnimatorListener() {
  @Override
  public void onAnimationStart(View view) {

  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationEnd(View view) {
   view.setVisibility(outGoingViewVisibility);
  }

  @Override
  public void onAnimationCancel(View view) {

  }
 }).start();

 incomingView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
 incomingView.setAlpha(0);
 ViewCompat.animate(incomingView).setListener(null).alpha(1).start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will be an option to use `ViewSwitcher`. 
Add a `viewSwitcher` with 2 ImageViews.

```
<ViewSwitcher xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/switcher"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/laxus"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/laxus2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

            </ViewSwitcher>`
```

On Activity `onCreate` add code

```
    ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher=(ViewSwitcher)findViewById(R.id. switcher); // initiate a ViewSwitcher
    Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_in_left); // load in  animation
    Animation out = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,android.R.anim.slide_out_right); // load out animation
    viewSwitcher.setInAnimation(in); // set in Animation for ViewSwitcher
    viewSwitcher.setOutAnimation(out); // set out Animation for ViewSwitcher
```

When you want to switch between `ImageViews` call method `viewSwitcher.showNext();` or `viewSwitcher.showPrevious();` 
To verify which view is displayed use `viewSwitcher.getCurrentView();`